# Can a javascript library that depend on other library have its own requirejs config and its own bower_components directory

Tags: javascript, module, bower

My title might be a bit confusing, but here is what I'm trying to find out if it's possible to do that.

I have a library called [`language-picker`](https://github.com/mozilla/webmaker-language-picker) and this library depends on few other libraries and using requirejs.

Now this library that I have is being include in many different apps, but one of the app does not have jquery and I don't really want to include it in the app directly.

The problem is that you can't have your own require-config.js file for your own library...

My question is:

1. Can I simply include my library without having to include path to other dependencies in the app?
2. If it is possible can the library have its own path for bower_components?

I just want to be able to let others use my library without having to do extra setup for path and so on.